# c++ Class Function return Struct element

Tags: c++, class, c++11, struct, return

so curiosity got me looking for an alternative method of returning specific data or part of a structure. I currently have a structure and class similar, if not exact to this:

```
struck Pos {
    Int x_{0},
        y_{0},
        z_{0};
};

class Object {
    private:
        Pos xyz_{ 0, 0, 0 };
    public:
        const Pos getPos() { return xyz_; }
};
```

Now this is without constructors and stuff. Anyway the I'm trying/wanting to return the **x_** of **xyz_** now I could just do:

```
const int getPosX() { return xyz_.x_; }
```

but that seems impractical as I'd have to do that 3 times as well as modify my main code to compensate for the changes. So wondered if there's an easier or better method for doing something like:

```
Object ob; // Empty I know but you get the idea?
int xValue = ob.getPos.x_;
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with `ob.getPos().x_`, which you pretty much had there?

Comment: `getPos` is a function so you'll need to use `()` to call it, but otherwise did you try that?

Comment: Ah, No sleep completely missed that. Thanks guy.

Comment: Btw, change `const Pos getPos()` to `Pos getPos() const` or `const Pos getPos() const`.  And things work better if you actually compile them before posting, as `struck` is clearly a typo.  It is hard for us to tell what mistakes are actual errors, and which are typos, in general cases.

Comment: be aware that your getPos method is returning a COPY of the Pos. Did you mean `const Pos& getPos() const` ?

Comment: Thanks for the btw Yakk. Cheer's Richard, I am aware of this but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ob.getPos().x_;
```

Worked, simply overlooked the `()`.